# java.util.Arrays not working java 8

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I recently updated to using Java 8 on my computer for eclipse. I had previously been using Java 7.  At first the update seemed to work fine as I could compile and run a simple `hello world`-program.  However, as I began to import previous projects that I had been working on that used the class `java.util.Arrays`, I got an error like `Arrays could not be resolved`.  I have been having a similar problem with the `PriorityQueue` class saying that,

> The type `java.util.Comparator` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required `.class` files.

Comment: Can you please post a minimally working example? It sounds like you have a problem with referencing the JDK in your project in Eclipse.

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.Comparator;`

Comment: Is the new JDK correctly mapped in eclipse?

Comment: In the import statement it says the import cannot be resolved

Comment: @popgalop Are you sure that the rt.jar of your JRE is in your classpath?

Comment: "I recently updated" What do you mean by updated? Did you manually uninstall old JDK? Did you installed Java 8 in new directory? Did you added this JDK to eclipse? Did you change your old project to use new JDK?

Comment: Look in 'Preferences > Java > Installed JREs' and check there is a JRE / JDK configured.

Comment: This sounds like a damaged Java installation or a thoroughly confused Eclipse workbench.

Comment: my CLASSPATH is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib my path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin and my JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

Comment: @popgalop: Eclipse doesn't care about these env variables. It uses its own configuration. Rather check your configuration at the location greg-449's comment suggested.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: I updated eclipse and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something really similar today. Not sure if its the same issue, but what I did was:

Open project explorer

Right click the project

Find "Configure Build Path"
[image]

In the window that opens, select the "Libraries" tab
[image]

Scroll down to JRE System Library (there was a red error symbol next to mine) and click the library.

[image]

In the top right, select the Edit button

Choose "Alternate JRE" and then pick (in your case) java 8
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you import previous Project then the Projects have the JDK for Java 7 in there Buildpath. You only have to update your Buildpathin the Projects to use Java 8. That should solve your problem.

Buildpaths don't will be updated automaticle for every Projects if you update your JDK.

Comment: Even when creating a new project it wont work.  It only creates a problem for those 2 classes